# On the notion of Gowers anti-uniform in "The primes contain arbitrarily long arithemtic progressions" by Green and Tao

Tags: nt.number-theory, ergodic-theory

In "[The primes contain arbitrarily long arithmetic progressions](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0404188v6)", Green and Tao say that $g$ is Gowers anti-uniform if 
$\| g \|_{(U^{k-1})^*} = O(1)$ and $\| g \|_{L^{\infty}} = O(1)$, and that $f$ is Gowers uniform if $\| f \|_{U^{k-1}}$ is "small".

If $f$ is not Gowers uniform, must $f$ be Gowers anti-uniform?

The definitions of $\| \cdot \|_{U^{k-1}}$ and $\| \cdot \|_{(U^{k-1})^*}$ can be found in (5.4) (p. 12) and (6.1) (p. 19) of the Green–Tao paper. (I would also be more than happy to type it out if that is the proper etiquette.)

UPDATE: The reason why I asked the question was the following. On page 28, right before the statement of Proposition 8.1 (Generalized Koopman-von Neumann structure theorem) the authors state "The key proposition is the following decomposition, which splits an arbitrary function into Gowers uniform and Gowers anti-uniform components (plus a negligible error)."

The proposition splits $f$ into two parts $(1 - 1_{\Omega})(f - \mathbb{E}( f | \mathcal{B}) )$ (This is the Gowers unifrom part because its $\| \cdot \|_{U^{k-1}}$ is small) and $(1 - 1_{\Omega})\mathbb{E}( f | \mathcal{B})$ 
which I am assuming is the Gowers anti-uniform part.

It is easy to show that this has a bounded (by O(1))$L_{\infty}$ norm. But in order to show it is Gowers anti-uniform as defined in the paper one also needs to show that its $\| \cdot \|_{(U^{k-1})^*}$ is bounded by $O(1)$. I was not sure how to do this and I wanted to get some ideas on how I could prove this (so by asking the above question I thought maybe I could get some ideas).

PS Let $N$ be a large prime, $\mathbb{Z}_N$ denote the residue class modulo $N$. The functions $f$ and $g$ are functions from $\mathbb{Z}_N$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I'm not sure about the need to reproduce the exact definitions of the norms, but at least it would be appropriate to say what kinds of objects $f$ and $g$ are.  Is there any reason to suspect that this dichotomy should hold?

Comment: I believe the structure of the argument is that you can split an $f$ into a "uniform" and a "structured" part. The model case is $k=2$ (I think), where there is a unique splitting in this way. For larger $k$, there is not a unique splitting, but the theorems say that you can split $f$ into a approximately uniform piece plus an approximately structured piece (where these "approximately" are quantitative statements).

Comment: I don't really understand your question, there's nowadays a full inverse theorem to Gowers norms by Green-Tao-Ziegler, so you're either "approximate nilsequence" (for which then you'll have large Gowers norm, as you'll correlate with nilcharacter) or you're "Nil-disjoint" (for example, coming from horocyclic flow or something). There has been a lot of progression (pun intended) in the field since the 06 paper. A good modern place to start looking into that is Tammy's EMS presentations - http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~tamarz/prime-EMS.pdf, http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~tamarz/Szemeredi.pdf

Comment: Thank you for all the comments. They are all very helpful! Let me edit my question to make it more precise.